# Why do IT departments still dictate what IT employees can use for hardware?

Tags: software-industry, employees

Are there legitimate business arguments for skimping on hardware and software for IT employees vs. say, giving employees an annual allotment to maintain their own hardware? Or is this just an old corporate IT habit that's hard to break?

Anecdotally, I've worked in several large organizations where hardware and software were restricted to the point of causing frustration amongst teammates and loss of productivity. In one situation, however, our department was given full choice and reign over our own hardware and software and things worked out just fine, so it appears that it's a viable solution to allow your IT staff to maintain their own desktop hardware and software. But I don't know why that isn't more common.

Comment: Because IT configures their policies like they configure their firewalls: default-deny, not default-accept :)

Comment: Have you ever considered all the systems that a company uses to run its operations?  Have you considered that companies generally will have limited resources?

Comment: Easier support aside, large companies tend to have dedicated hardware & software vendors. They do bulk purchase and this drive the cost down. Also these companies are likely to give newcomers hardware used by ex-employee.

Comment: @JBKing sure I've considered that. But the math is still odd. The annual cost of a decent laptop in the grand scheme of the cost of an IT employee is what? .5% at most? Seems like an odd item to limit given the ROI one can get by spending a little bit more on it.

Comment: @fapDaddy well, I don't know that you can brush 'easier support' aside. IT workers, it seems, have much higher demands on desktop support as they have to have so much specialized software and permission settings and network access and the like. Seems the support team could *save* support costs by passing some of the tasks on to the IT worker directly. Bulk purchasing makes sense, but, again, hardware is such a small part of the overall cost of an IT worker. But it's also the one thing that can really boost IT worker productivity.

Comment: What size company are you looking at here?  For a start-up that is running on the founder's savings, a decent laptop could be a really non-trivial sum of money to spend here and that is without considering how often one would want to upgrade that hardware.

Comment: @DA it appears that you have combined two issues: you want bleeding edge hardware/software and your company is cheap; with the issue of the ability to make any change you want. Your rejection of everything that doesn't confirm your view makes this a rant.

Comment: @JBKing ah, apologies, I guess I wasn't explicit in my post. I was talking specifically about large corporations--typically fortune 500 size.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep I suppose it can be construed as a rant, but I was sincerely asking if there were *legitimate* arguments for it. A lot of the answers are posting *typical* arguments for it, but they aren't legitimate when you run the numbers.

Comment: Maybe the typical arguments are legitimate. You have rejected the desire to have a limited list of systems, ease of support, discounts , cost, security...

Comment: @mhoran_psprep in the context of the employee base as a whole, I could see those typical arguments as being legitimate. But in the context of IT departments, I've never seen them to be legitimate. And from what I've witnessed, when IT employees are given wider berth  to control their own hardware and software things become MUCH more efficient and productive (ie, saving money). I'm not rejecting the 'desire' for those, but rather contesting the actual total cost savings the purport to have. (No argument the immediate cost savings can be justified, but not the loss of productivity)

Comment: @DA I think that's the problem with a lot of companies. IT department is run like a factory and IT worker is treated like a factory worker. The company buy a machine and assign a factory worker to it. There's absolutely no needs to replace the machine unless it is broken beyond repair. If the production can't keep up with demand, they will simply add another machine. Eventually the factory worker will feel unmotivated and leave. Without consulting the worker, management assumed that's the nature of all workers. Hence all workers will never get motivated and be productive. And the cycle repeat.

Comment: @fapdaddy, I think you are right. A lot of business is still run under the 'factory' model. In fact, the failings of a lot of software development models, IMHO, is that it's still based on factory floor concepts. Which just don't make any sense in the world of IT.

Answer (score 7):

Differing hardware complicates support. They require different drivers, patches, and expertise. In even a small company this can quickly become a pain. Over time they will be forced away from a single platform, to multiple platforms during the life time of the machines, but they still want to keep the options to a minimum.

Limiting hardware and software to a small list of options also allows the company to get volume discounts. It also allows the IT department to quickly configure a replacement machine when one is needed.

Most companies expect that hardware costs will be X dollars per employee every 3-4 years, not x/4 dollars every year.

Comment: I understand the 'complicates support' argument, but not the reality of it when we're talking IT staff. IT employees tend to understand things like drivers and the like and seem quite adept and maintaining their own hardware when left to their own devices.

Comment: Employers would generally prefer IT employees did something useful for the business, rather than being left to their own devices to fiddle with their own hardware of choice.

Comment: @Carson63000 I don't know if you work in IT or not, but typically, at least in large corporations, IT employees often can't do useful things because their hardware/software is so locked down. For instance, for me to get software installed, I often have to wait 3 days. That can be a giant performance hit. And there are studies that show those with large monitors are actually more productive than those with small monitors. Etc.

Comment: At another company, we were tasked with testing our web site on iOS devices. Yet we had no OSX machines to run virtualization on, and no internal servers to connect our iOS devices too. Silly restrictions like that.

Comment: "Most companies expect that hardware costs will be X dollars per employee every 3-4 years" I guess that sums up the problem. Corporations don't understand the value of keeping their IT staff properly equipped. I could see that as a *legitimate* argument, but an incorrect one, given the typical loss of efficiency and productivity in corporate IT departments that I've seen due to underpowered equipment for the staff.

Comment: If you're writing software for your company, wouldn't it be useful if it ran correctly on someone else's machine besides just your own?  Having some of that standardized helps in that.  I'm not saying you should have substandard equipment, but it should have some similarities to the person who is going to be running your software.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek that was exactly my point. We were building iOS optimized web sites. But had no actual iOS nor OSX devices to actual test on. The amount of time wasted in coming up with workarounds seemed to greatly outweigh the cost of allowing our department access to better (and compatible) hardware.

Comment: @DA - Oh.  The way I read the question, it sounded like you wanted to define yourself what was the best hardware.  That is something that ideally your managment would make sure you have: appropriate and adequate.  So your question is more about bad management than you buying your own hardware.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek yes, that's a good way to put it. I guess, in summary, in the larger corporations I've worked in, I've seen a lot of bad management decisions in terms of not providing adequate tools for IT staff. This has always confused me. ;)

Answer (score 4):

### Hope for the Best, Make Rules for the Worst

Rules are designed for the employee with the least common sense. There is always that one employee who spoils it for everyone else. The bigger the company is, the higher the level of incompetence possible from the pool of employees.

For instance, my previous company had us bring two computers on business trips. One was our work PC we used in the office, and the second could connect to the internet. In the past, someone decided it was a good idea to browse some seedy sites on the internet on his work PC, got a virus, and brought it back to the office where it promptly wreaked havoc on the network. So rather than trust that the employees won't look at questionable content on their work PC, they just prevented anyone from connecting to the internet outside of the office at all.

### Risk vs. Reward

Because of the unique individuals who manage to crash the entire company network because they don't have the common sense to think before acting, the risk of not moderating behavior of your average employee is huge. For instance, the same company that forced us to use separate PCs for the internet had the factory and office connected to the same network. The fear of virus was amplified by the fact that a virus could shut down production of the factory causing massive losses in productivity and revenues.

On the other hand, the reward of giving employees control is much less tangible. Someone can argue why the PCs should be separate giving the worst-case example, but how can you quantify the harm to employee morale at having to lug around two separate PCs when traveling halfway across the world? Or the losses of having to move data to a separate PC for presentations to the customer?

### The Default is "No"

In big companies they cannot judge the individual well. So the default is "no". You have the set of rules, and if you want to do anything outside of those rules, you need to get special permission. This is much safer for the company, and it allows them to make decisions on a case-by-case basis.

When you have smaller companies, the people who are managing risk can judge the risk of individual employees much better, and have looser rules where they can speak out and say "no" on a case-by-case basis before it causes a serious problem.

This is a conservative approach and has to do with what [Peopleware calls "Defensive Management"](http://javatroopers.com/Peopleware.html#defensive_management). Right or wrong, it is the default for most companies. The more we rely on IT, the more difficult it is to give power to an average employee (even one in IT) to potentially screw over the entire network.

Comment: "Rules are designed for the employee with the least common sense" = very true! And I completely understand broadly speaking. But when talking specifically of IT employees, I sure hope companies aren't hiring IT folks with the least common sense when it comes to IT. :)

Comment: No company **intends** to hire someone with the least common sense, but it happens anyway, doesn't it? The hiring process is a human process, and humans make mistakes.

Comment: true. But given that there are so many readily available ways for an IT worker to do major damage *within* the confines of the IT policies, not letting them install needed software themselves seems like such a petty thing to restrict that ultimately costs the company time and money due to lack of productivity (and having to hire another employee just to install software)

Comment: A malicious employee can always do a lot of harm. Malicious employees, by virtue of being malicious, will go through great lengths to do bad things and don't care about the rules/policies. The goal of the rules is to protect against the harm caused by ignorant employees. And yes, while it is nice to think that all IT folk are responsible and know what not to do, it simply isn't true. Have you tried to ask your company why that is the policy? They may have a great answer for you.

Comment: it's not 'my' company as much as the last 3 fortune 500s I've worked at. The arguments are just as those stated. And I wasn't necessarily referring to malicious employees. I'm saying an IT worker, who, say, has access to a production server, can easily screw that up. But, of course, they need access to the server to do their job. So it seems illogical that that same worker wouldn't be trusted to install a software upgrade to visual studio, for instance, on their own laptop and instead has to have yet another employee handle that task.